# Splitting String array without using split(String regex) method

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a String array that contains the "_" characheter in each element of it, I want to get rid of these characters.

I can do this task simply by using String [] split(String regex) method, but I don't want  to it by this function because  I will use this code in J2ME  later.

I have write a code to do this task but the output are strange characters
[Ljava.lang.String;@19821f
[Ljava.lang.String;@addbf1  !!!

```
public class StringFragementation {

static public   String [] mymethod(String [] mystring)
{

   String ss [] =new String[mystring.length];

   for(int j=0;j<mystring.length;j++)

   {
   ss[j] =  mystring[j].replace('_',',');

   }

   return ss ;

   }
 public static void main(String [] args)

  {

   String []  s = {"Netherlands_Iceland_Norway_Denmark","Usa_Brazil_Argentina"};

   for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++)
   {

 System.out.println("" + mymethod(s) );

   }

       }

       }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have modified your code. It will give you desired output. use following code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] s = {"Netherlands_Iceland_Norway_Denmark", "Usa_Brazil_Argentina"};
    String[] finalString = mymethod(s);        
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("" + finalString[i]);
    }
}

static public String[] mymethod(String[] mystring) {
    String ss[] = new String[mystring.length];
    for (int j = 0; j < mystring.length; j++) {
        ss[j] = mystring[j].replace('_', ',');
    }
    return ss;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In Java, each *object* has [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method, the default is displaying the class name representation, then adding `@` and then the hashcode.

`ss` is an *array* of `String`s. You should use [`Arrays#toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5B%5D%29), which is implemented [this way](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.toString%28int%5B%5D%29):

```
3860     public static String toString(int[] a) { {
3861        if (a == null)
3862            return "null";
3863        int iMax = a.length - 1;
3864        if (iMax == -1)
3865            return "[]";
3866
3867        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
3868        b.append('[');
3869        for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
3870            b.append(a[i]);
3871            if (i == iMax)
3872                return b.append(']').toString();
3873            b.append(", ");
3874        }
3875    }
```

Or, you can do:

```
for(String str : mymethod(s)) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Comment: I cann't use Arrays object in j2me version any alternative solution plz?

Comment: @ElhadiMamoun See "Or, you can do:".

Answer (score 0):

What you see there is the result of the `toString()` method when invoked on arrays. It's almost meaningless. What is printed is the type of the array followed by its hashCode.

Use `java.util.Arrays.toString()` to transform an array into a meaningful String representation.

Comment: I cann't use Arrays object in j2me version any alternative solution plz?

Comment: Yes. So use a for loop. `for (String s : array) {System.out.println(s);}`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyDisticntElements {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int [] nums = {2,3,4,5,8,7,7};
        MyDisticntElements.printDuplicate(nums);
    }
    public static void printDuplicate(int[] arr)
    {
        for(int i =0; i<arr.length; i++)
        {
            boolean duplicate = false;
            for(int j = 0; j<i; j++)
            {
                if(arr[i] == arr[j])
                {
                    duplicate = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(duplicate)
            {
                System.out.println(arr[i]+"");
            }
        }
    }
}
```